# Generating function(really simple????)

Tags: probability, statistics, generating-functions

With $X_n$ as a discrete random variable that takes the values $1,2,\dots,n$ with equal probability $\frac1n$.

I want to:

Evaluate the probability generating function of $X_n$!!!

---

$G_{X_n}= \sum_{x=1}^n P(X_n = x) z^x = \sum_{x=1}^n \frac1n z^x=z^x$

Is it really that simple?!?

Comment: The sum of n constant terms is n times the constant. $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n c = c n$.  Also, where did the $k$ come from?

Comment: @GrahamKemp How is that possible? There is no operator for $x$ to be assigned?

Comment: $\sum_{x=1}^n c = c + c + \ldots c = c n$

Comment: Also, and mainly, $G(z) = E[z^X] = \sum_{x} p(x) z^{\color{red}{x}}$; IE: the exponent is $x$ not to $k$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you for that[although I feel dumb for forgetting how to do Riemann sums :( ]

Comment: $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n z^x \neq n z^x$  That only works for constant terms (wrt the iterator).  This is a *geometric series*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Geometric series:** *from first principles*

Let: $$S_n = \sum\limits_{x=1}^n z^x = z + z^2 + \cdots + z^{n-1} + z^n$$

Then: $$ z\cdot S_n = \sum\limits_{x=1}^n z^{x+1} = z^2 + \cdots + z^n + z^{n+1}$$

Telescoping: $$(1-z)S_n = z - z^{n+1}$$

Finally: $$S_n = \dfrac{z(1-z^n)}{1-z}$$

Comment: So here, we multiply both sides by $z$, minus the first equation from the second, ridding all of the terms but for the first and the added last. That makes sense, and then dividing it back over to receive the original sequence in direct form. Makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

It should be
\begin{align}
G_{X_n}(z) &= \sum_{1 \le x \le n} \frac{z^x}{n} \\
  &= \frac{z(1 - z^n)}{n (1 - z)}
\end{align}

Comment: How was that step between sum and direct form obtained?

Comment: @user151558 It's a geometric series.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think I remember in calculus a long time ago doing $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$, Is this what I want?